# David M. Burton Inequality exercise: $P^2_{n+3}<P_nP_{n+1}P_{n+2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $P_n$ denote $n$th prime number.
Then for $n$≥3,
$$P^2_{n+3}<P_nP_{n+1}P_{n+2}$$

I came across this problem while reading a book about number theory under the chapter Primes.

Comment: I have carefully studied the problem and then given it a required tag

Comment: https://books.google.com/books/about/Elementary_Number_Theory.html?id=2dI3AwAAQBAJ

Comment: It is elementary number theory @Babydesta

Comment: What I am saying is,if you can solve the problem you're welcome. But if you can't solve it then why to get offended

Comment: One who can solve it will not ask weather it is elementary number theory of just number theory

Comment: @HowardDickson, sorry if I came too harsh. not my intention.

Comment: Be careful next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Bertrand's postulate, $P_{n+3} < 2 P_{n+2} < 4 P_{n+1}$. Hence
$$P_{n+3}^2 < 8 P_{n+1} P_{n+2} \,.$$
We are done if $P_n \geq 8$, i.e. if $n \geq 5$. It remains to observe that
$$13^2 < 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11$$
and
$$ 17^2 < 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \,:$$
The squares on the left are less than $300$, and the products on the right are larger than $300$.

Comment: I understood it sir but I would really appreciate a more general proof of the last step

Comment: Which step?${}$

Comment: The squares on the left are less than 300, and the products on the right are larger than 300

Comment: No problem sir,it's done

Comment: Thank you for your time

Comment: You're welcome. I formulated it in that way, because that's how I checked that the products on the right are larger, without computing them.

Comment: $P_{n+3}^2 < 8 P_{n+1} P_{n+2} \,.$ for $P_n > 8$, we get $P_{n+3}^2 < P_n P_{n+1} P_{n+2}$, then he checked for primes between 3 and 8.